# How to get Null values of records in aerospike

Tags: null, record, aerospike, aql

[image]

I'm working with aerospike. Using AQL, I inserted some data. I want to get null values of records with particular fields in aerospike. I'm tagging picture in that picture one record does not have a name its empty space

Answer (score 5):

Aeropsike is schemaless - each record is self describing. Any bin that is non-null is part of the record. Any bin that is updated to null actually gets deleted from the record. So, think in terms of units of record instead of a table with columns.  You can query for a specific bin from a record and if not found, Aeropsike will return a null.  Here is the java API:

```
public final Record get(Policy policy,
         Key key,
         String... binNames)
                 throws AerospikeException
Read record header and bins for specified key. The policy can be used to specify timeouts.
Specified by:
get in interface IAerospikeClient
Parameters:
policy - generic configuration parameters, pass in null for defaults
key - unique record identifier
binNames - bins to retrieve
Returns:
if found, return record instance. If not found, return null.
Throws:
AerospikeException - if read fails
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on what happens to a bin when i put null on them? is that a process that delete the bin? what happening? is the LUT of the record is updated on insert null to the bin? is it shipped over XDR?

Comment: null --> deletes a bin, yes. what's happening? --> an updated version of the record is re-written in the system with updated LUT. If you are using XDR, that will cause that record to ship via xdr.

Answer (score 1):

Ran some test code - the record key is valid with some other bins:

```
userRecord = client.get(null, userKey, "notThereBin");
    if (userRecord != null) {
        console.printf("\nINFO: User record with notThereBin read successfully! Here are the details:\n");
        console.printf("notThereBin:  " + userRecord.getValue("notThereBin") + "\n");
    } else {
        console.printf("ERROR: User record not found!\n");
    }
```

and the output is:

```
    INFO: User record with notThereBin read successfully! Here are the details:

notThereBin:  null
```